# Mage_Catalog_Model_Category to Varien_Data_Tree_Node

Tags: magento-1.9, category, navigation

I have to debug some custom templates and find an error. What I have found now is that the function that lead to the error needs a `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` to work, but in some cases this function gets a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`.

Now my question is, can I somehow create a `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` out of a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` ?

### Edit some code:

in some cases:

```
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($store_cats as $_category){
  drawChildren($_category, 0, $path_ids);
}
```

while here is `$_category` from type: Varien_Data_Tree_Node. This works cause the function drawChildren needs a Varien_Data_Tree_Node.

In other cases the same function is called via:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
drawChildren($_category, 0, $path_ids);
```

while here is `$_category` from type: Mage_Catalog_Model_Category. And this does not work. So my idea is to create a Varien_Data_Tree_Node but not from the rootcategory, but from the category in Mage_Catalog_Model_Category as topcategory.

the function itself looks like this:

```
function drawChildren($category, $recLevel, $pathIds) {
    // small security measure in case looped categories are possible
    if ($recLevel > 5) {
        break;
    }

    $children = $category->getChildren();
    echo get_class($category);
    $childrenCount = $children->count();

    $_helper= Mage::helper('catalog/category');


    if ($childrenCount > 0) {

        foreach($children as $child) {

            // check if the current child has children on its own
            // call the function recursively if it does
            $grandchildren = $child->getChildren();
            $gCount = $grandchildren->count();

            if ($gCount > 0 && in_array($child->getId(), $pathIds)) {
                drawItem($_helper->getCategoryUrl($child), $child->getName(), $child->getId(), 0, $pathIds);
                echo '<ul class="subnavi">';
                drawChildren($child, $recLevel + 1, $pathIds);
                echo '</ul></li>';
            }
            else {
                drawItem($_helper->getCategoryUrl($child), $child->getName(), $child->getId(), 1, $pathIds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have some logical issue, because Varien_Data_Tree_Node is simple_xml object. However Mage_Catalog_Model_Category is another object which nohow refers to simple_xml

Comment: i try to provide some code now. But Varien_Data_Tree_Node can be the category tree when you get it with `(new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation())->getStoreCategories()`. So I would like to have the same, but not from the rootcategory, but from the category I have in my Category Obj.

Comment: @Marius added some code. Hope it gets clearer now. What I would like to do is to create a `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` like the one you get with `(new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation())->getStoreCategories()`, but not from the root category, but from a custom category.